# the function of the preposition "of" in a phrase ", those of the dynamic nature of,"

Tags: prepositions

I'd very appreciate if somebody can help me understand the exact function of the preposition in the phrase between the two commas!

> Everywhere we find the same leading motifs; the concepts of organization showing new characteristics and laws at each level, ***those of the dynamic nature of***, and the antitheses within reality
>   <sub>(Bertalanffy 1952, recited by Golley 1993:33). [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22so%20quippy%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22characteristics%20and%20laws%20at%20each%20level%22&tbm=bks)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It's an awkward sentence that smells of the lamp; it's not at all clear whether *those* refers to *concepts* or to *characteristics and laws*;  but I think what is meant is:

> Everywhere we find the same leading motifs, to wit [that should be a colon, not a semicolon, after motifs]
>   the concepts
>   - of organization showing new characteristics and laws at each level
>   - of the dynamic nature of reality
>      and
>   - of the antitheses within reality.

It probably works better in German.

Comment: I read *those* as referring back to the *motifs*, of which there are essentially three. Those concerned with characteristics/laws at each level of organisation, those concerned with the dynamic nature of reality, and those concerned with the contrasts/contradictions within reality. But it's not really a matter of *language* - the reality of *this* question is it's all about understanding dense ***metaphysical concepts***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It really is a colon in the original, and I don't think even a German biologist would cross that boundary for his referent when at least three candidates lie between.

Comment: I really think we're splitting hairs here. Can there really be any difference between of *the motif of the concept of the antitheses within reality*, and just *the motif of the antitheses within reality*? I don't see either the grammar or the semantics force one interpretation over the other.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yah; hard cases make bad law, and bad writing makes pointless criticism. He tries to make his sentence say more than the language wants him to, and in consequence communicates less. Great Mother Language always wins.

Comment: I'm certainly not going to wade through all that turgid prose to find out what exactly Bertalanffy means by *the antitheses within reality*. I'm used to thinking that most *meaningful* concepts/motifs involve something that can be "quantified" - by placing it somewhere on a line having "opposites" at each end of the scale. So I'll just assume that's what he means - but if I didn't already have that concept, I doubt I'd get it from OP's text.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a comma after "within": "concepts of organization showing new characteristics and laws at each level, those of the dynamic nature of, and the antitheses within, reality"

The sentence would be clearer again with a colon: "concepts of organization showing new characteristics and laws at each level: those of the dynamic nature of, and the antitheses within, reality"

So: "those" refers to the characteristics and laws, which the concepts of organization show.

Now we have:

*the concepts show the characteristics and laws of the dynamic nature of reality

and

*the concepts show the characteristics and laws of the antitheses within reality

I believe this is what was intended.